# Send logs from Javascript to ElasticSearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

Is there any Javascript api that allows me to send post requests, either directly through axios post or through Node JS, to Elastic Search?  This is to SEND logs to Elastic Search.

Comment: Send logs meaning a set of log files or logs getting generated in javascript app? can you explain.

Comment: I mean send logs generated in JavaScript app.

Comment: If you have them in a folder use logstash or filebeat to push to es

Comment: There's no direct way?

Answer (score 0):

You can send POST requests using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
```